Why does such a simple integral crash my kernel?
Unprotect[NumberQ, Conjugate, Abs, Sign];
Conjugate[Subscript[t, n_Integer]] = Subscript[t, n];
Conjugate[t] = t;
Conjugate[\[Delta]] = \[Delta];
Abs[\[Delta]] = \[Delta];
Sign[\[Delta]] = 1;
Conjugate[\[CapitalOmega]] = \[CapitalOmega];
Conjugate[t1] = t1;
Abs[t1] = t1;
Conjugate[t2] = t2;
Abs[t2] = t2;
Conjugate[t3] = t3;
Abs[t3] = t3;
Conjugate[t4] = t4;
Abs[t4] = t4;
NumberQ[h] = True;
NumberQ[h^n_] = True;
NumberQ[\[CapitalOmega]] = True;
NumberQ[\[CapitalOmega]^n_] = True;
NumberQ[E] = True;
NumberQ[E^n_] = True;
NumberQ[\[Delta]] = True;
NumberQ[\[Delta]^n_] = True;
NumberQ[t] = True;
NumberQ[t^n_] = True;
NumberQ[t1] = True;
NumberQ[t1^n_] = True;
NumberQ[t2] = True;
NumberQ[t2^n_] = True;
NumberQ[t3] = True;
NumberQ[t3^n_] = True;
NumberQ[t4] = True;
NumberQ[t4^n_] = True;
NumberQ[\[Alpha]] = True;
NumberQ[\[Alpha]^n_] = True;
NumberQ[Sy] = True;
NumberQ[Sy^n_] = True;
NumberQ[f[_, _]] = True;
NumberQ[f[_, _]^n_Integer] = True;
NumberQ[Inactive[f][_, _]] = True;
NumberQ[Inactive[f][_, _]^n_Integer] = True;
NumberQ[fc[_, _]] = True;
NumberQ[fc[_, _]^n_Integer] = True;
NumberQ[Inactive[fc][_, _]] = True;
NumberQ[Inactive[fc][_, _]^n_Integer] = True;
NumberQ[Conjugate[_]] = True;
NumberQ[Conjugate[_]^n_Integer] = True;
NumberQ[Integrate[_, _]] = True;
NumberQ[Integrate[_, _]^n_Integer] = True;
Protect[NumberQ, Conjugate, Abs, Sign];

$Assumptions = {Element[{j, k}, PositiveIntegers], 
   Element[\[Delta], PositiveReals]};

Integrate[E^(
 I j t1 \[Delta] - I \[Theta]), {t1, 0, (2 \[Pi])/\[Delta]}]

This should be enough to reproduce the issue. You can run the integral once but then run it a few more times and for me it crashes. It's good to compute once but I have some more complex expressions which I'd like to integrate so it shouldn't be crashing for such a simple expression. I find that without all the initialisation code above, the integral works fine but all that initialisation code somehow breaks the integral.
The NumberQ overrides are necessary to make some symbols commutative. I am working with boson operators and I am not aware of other methods to get mathematica to distinguish scalars from non-commuting varaibles

What is expected is that the integral will result in zero. It's a very simple integral. bit rude of you to provide literally zero insight and accuse me of monkeying around. If you have an alternative to overriding NumberQ I will try it immediately.

Sorry to come across as snarky.  I would imagine that the internal code used by Integrate makes certain assumptions about how system functions like NumberQ, Conjugate, Abs, etc, will behave.  If those other system functions misbehave then you have undefined behavior.

Cannot reproduce it in 14.1 on Windows. Executing Unprotect[NumberQ, Conjugate, Abs, Sign];..Protect[NumberQ, Conjugate, Abs, Sign]; and after that executing $Assumptions = {Element[{j, k}, PositiveIntegers],     Element[\[Delta], PositiveReals]}; Integrate[E^(  I j t1 \[Delta] - I \[Theta]), {t1, 0, (2 \[Pi])/\[Delta]}], I obtain 0 without any excesses.

I agree with @JasonB. NumberQ is a low-level check and is used in many places where an input outside its intended realm might cause trouble. That's the insight of the original comment.

(1) Based on the stated goals I am still not clear on why these symbols require changes via Abs,Conjugate and the like. One could note in the assumptions that delta>0 for example (which more or less is done, although I'm not sure how wellIntegrate handles PositiveReals since its assumptions mechanism predates the newer domains)....

(2) Something like this might do what you want. `In[4]:= ii =
Integrate[E^(Ijt1*delta - I *theta), {t1, 0, (2 [Pi])/delta},
Assumptions -> {delta > 0, j > 0, Element[j, Integers]}]
Out[4]= -((I E^(-I theta) (-1 + E^(2 I j [Pi])))/(delta j))
In[5]:= FullSimplify[ii, Element[j, Integers] && j >= 1]
Out[5]= 0
In[1]:= aaThe second step is needed at least for now becauseIntegrate` does not do much with integrality assumptions. This might change in future.

@user64494 and if you re-run it several times does it ever crash? This is important because I have many of such integrals

I can get this smaller example to crash fairly often. `Unprotect[NumberQ, Abs];
Abs[t1] = t1;
NumberQ[t1] = True;
NumberQ[E^n_] = True;
Protect[NumberQ, Abs];
Limit[(t1 - 2* Pi/del)^(1 - eps)(E^(I(2jPi - 1))), {t1,
eps} -> {(2*Pi)/del, 0}, Direction -> {1, -1},
Assumptions -> del > 0]. I will file a bug report when I reach my office machine. Though given the changes to NumericQ` there is no guarantee it will be amenable to repair.

@DanielLichtblau thank you very much. It seems I will need to work around it by just using setcommutative/ setnoncommutative from the NCAlgebra package. Then maybe I can avoid fiddling with NumberQ

@Luca: On your request I executed the code a dozen times consequently and with  breaks in time. Every time the result was 0 without any excess.

@DanielLichtblau: Indeed, Unprotect[NumberQ, Abs]; Abs[t1] = t1; NumberQ[t1] = True; NumberQ[E^n_] = True; Protect[NumberQ, Abs];  Limit[(t1 - 2* Pi/del)^(1 - eps)*(E^(I*(2*j*Pi - 1))), {t1,     eps} -> {(2*Pi)/del, 0}, Direction -> {1, -1},   Assumptions -> del > 0] quits the kernel in short time.
